# Are these equivalent for adding a unique constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

I wonder if the following queries are equivalent.
I want to add a unique constraint for two of the columns in the movie table

```
CREATE TABLE Movie (
 title VARCHAR(255),
 year INTEGER,
 …
 producerC# INTEGER,
 UNIQUE (title, year)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Movie (
 title VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
 year INTEGER UNIQUE,
 …
 producerC# INTEGER
);
```

Comment: They are different

Comment: In the real world neither is a valid constraint - several examples here https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78328/907

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version will enforce that the *combination* of movie title and movie year will always be unique.  So, the following two combinations are permitted:

```
Invasion of the Body Snatchers, 1956
Invasion of the Body Snatchers, 1978
```

But note that the same movie *can* appear more than once, provided that it does not do so with the same year.

The second version requires that each movie title and year separately are unique.  This would mean that Body Snatchers can only appear once with one given year.

Based on my sample data, I would guess that you want to go with the first version.

Comment: The more pressing issue with the second version is that also means only one movie can be added per year. Period.

Answer (score 1):

No they are different.

```
 UNIQUE (title, year)
```

implies that combination of title and year is unique.
So title ="alpha", year="2022" and title ="beta", year="2022" are unique as per this .

```
title VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
 year INTEGER UNIQUE,
```

implies that individual columns must have unique values.
So the example above violates the above constraint as year 2022 is repeated.